# Debugging clang with gdb

Tags: gdb, clang

When I build clang I add the flag `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.
Now I want to debug my clang.
I do `gdb build/bin/clang`. But when I want to add a breakpoint `break llvm/lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/AddressSanitizer:instrumentStoreInstruction` and gdb throw an error

> **Function "instrumentStoreInstruction" not defined in "/llvm/lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/AddressSanitizer.cpp".**

But prototype and definition of that function are in that file.

Comment: Try `b AddressSanitizer.cpp:123`.

Comment: it worked but at 123 line not a definition of the `instrumentStoreInstruction`

Comment: That was an example. Just use whatever line you want.

Comment: Its doesnt work when I try this `b AddressSanitizer.cpp:instrumentStoreInstruction`

Comment: Is that function defined at the global level of AddressSanitizer.cpp, or is it in the AddressSanitizer class? I couldn't find it at all in llvm 5.0.1 source/

Comment: That function defined in the AddressSanitizer struct.
P.S. I tried this `b AddressSanitizer.cpp:AddressSanitizer.cpp::instrumentStoreInstruction`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick And Im using llvm 3.8

Comment: OK. I don't see `instrumentStoreInstruction` in the 3.8.0 or 3.8.1 source; did you add it yourself? Anyway, struct should have the same effect as class, so try `class::function`, such as `b AddressSanitizer::instrumentStoreInstruction` or `b AddressSanitizer.cpp:AddressSanitizer::instrumentStoreInstruction`.

Comment: Another thing to try: find the `AddressSanitizer.o` file - it may be in the `lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/Release+Asserts` directory - and run `nm -C AddressSanitizer.o | grep instrumentStoreInstruction` and see what the fully-qualified name is.

Comment: Here is the result 
000000000000c35c t (anonymous namespace)::AddressSanitizer::instrumentStoreInstruction(llvm::StoreInst*, llvm::Instruction*)

000000000000d6c0 r (anonymous namespace)::AddressSanitizer::instrumentStoreInstruction(llvm::StoreInst*, llvm::Instruction*)::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__

Comment: I said that when I try this `b AddressSanitizer.cpp:AddressSanitizer::instrumentStoreInstruction` it didnt work

Comment: And this `AddressSanitizer::instrumentStoreInstruction(llvm::StoreInst*, llvm::Instruction*)` doesnt work

Comment: and gdb not working not only with that function I tried to set a breakpoint at other functions (with functions of their native code too) and there is a same problem

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You are a GENIUS man)))

Comment: I forget that my functions are in  anonymous namespace))) and there are only accessible  within that file